# All elements in class change colour when any one element in class is hovered

Tags: css, hover, flexbox

http://jsfiddle.net/meh/tdmdunpn/1/

```
.c1:hover {background-color: #b00806}
```

I wish to have all cells of this flex table (not an actual table) with the class .c1 to change background colour to the lighter red colour when any one element with the class .c1 is hovered.

I am looking to use pure CSS without JS but I am willing to use if necessary.

Please do not suggest using an actual table, as that is inconvenient for my purposes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need Javascript to do that.

If you're interested in Jquery I would probably manage it by toggling a new class based on an existing selector.

```
.slide:hover, .slideHover {
    background-color: rgba(176,8,6,0.45);
}

$( ".c1" ).hover(function() {
  $(".c1" ).toggleClass("slideHover");
});
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tdmdunpn/6/)

```js
$( ".c1" ).hover(function() {
  $(".c1" ).toggleClass("slideHover");
});
```

```css
#slider {
 clear: both;
 width: 100%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
 height: 250px;
 display: flex;
 flex: 0 1 auto;
 flex-direction: column;
 flex-wrap: no-wrap;
 background-color: white;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slide {
 height: 100%;
 min-width: 100%;
 width: 33.3%;
 border: thin black solid;
 border-right: medium black solid;
 border-left: medium black solid;
 flex-grow: 1;
 display: flex;
 flex: 0 1 auto;
 flex-flow: no-wrap row;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slide:hover, .slideHover {
 background-color: rgba(176,8,6,0.45);
}

.slide:first-child {
 border-bottom: medium #b00806 solid;
 border-top: medium black solid; 
}

.slide:last-child {
 border-bottom: medium black solid; 
}

.row {
 border-right: thin black solid;
 flex-grow: 1;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row:first-child {
 flex-grow: 3; 
}

.row:nth-child(2) {
 flex-grow: 2; 
}

.row:nth-child(3) {
 flex-grow: 2; 
}

.row:last-child {
 border-right: none; 
}

.row:hover {
 background-color: rgba(143,6,4,0.48); 
}

.tab1text {
 line-height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 5px; 
}

.row {
 width: 1px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tab-content1" class="tab-content">
                <div id="w1"><div id="slider">
        <div class="slide">
                     <div class="row c1"><a class="tab1text" href=""></a></div>
                        <div class="row"></div>
                        <div class="row"></div>
                        <div class="row"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                     <div class="row c1"></div>
                        <div class="row"></div>
                        <div class="row"></div>
                        <div class="row"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                     <div class="row c1"></div>
                        <div class="row"></div>
                        <div class="row"></div>
                        <div class="row"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                     <div class="row c1"></div>
                        <div class="row"></div>
                        <div class="row"></div>
                        <div class="row"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                     <div class="row c1"></div>
                        <div class="row"></div>
                        <div class="row"></div>
                        <div class="row"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                     <div class="row c1"></div>
                        <div class="row"></div>
                        <div class="row"></div>
                        <div class="row"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                     <div class="row c1"></div>
                        <div class="row"></div>
                        <div class="row"></div>
                        <div class="row"></div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: thank you! every other js code i've tried from other forums has failed, but this works perfectly.

Comment: i've hit an issue in which this functions perfectly within jsfiddle but when i insert it into my locally stored code and open in firefox (latest version), it doesn't work. do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I assume you have referenced/linked jquery locally and included a `docready` function ...as for why the Stack Snippets doesn't work..I have no idea. It does in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible using pure css. You can use the following jquery code to achieve this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".c1").hover(function () {
        $(".c1").css("background-color", "rgba(176,8,6,0.45)");
    }, function () {
        $(".c1").css("background-color", "white");
    });
});
```

Explanation: When we hover on `".c1"`, then it will change the `background-color` to whatever color(say light red color) and on `hover out` it will change it to `'white'` again as specified by the second part of the `hover()`.

See the updated fiddle: "http://jsfiddle.net/tdmdunpn/12/"